# How to use timeouts with websockets whilst not affecting application safety?

Tags: multithreading, haskell, asynchronous, concurrency, websocket

I am writing a game server in Haskell with websockets. I need to time a player action and update the game with a timeout action is the socket does not receive an action from the client in the specified amount of time.

I am experiencing a sporadic issue whereby sometimes the execution of the timeout results in a *ConnectionClosed* exception being thrown. If this exception is not caught then the exception kills the socket for the thread and disconnects the client.

However even if I catch the exception as per the code below the client socket is still disconnected. This puzzles me.

I found a similar issue on the tracker of the websockets library I am using:

> If a thread is killed while receiveData or similar is blocking, the
>   TCP connection is closed and a ConnectionClosed exception is thrown.
>   https://github.com/jaspervdj/websockets/issues/101

```
handleSocketMsg :: MsgHandlerConfig -> MsgIn -> IO ()
handleSocketMsg msgHandlerConfig@MsgHandlerConfig {..} msg = do
  print $ "parsed msg: " ++ show msg
  msgOutE <- runExceptT $ runReaderT (gameMsgHandler msg) msgHandlerConfig
  either
    (\err -> sendMsg clientConn $ ErrMsg err)
    (handleNewGameState serverStateTVar)
    msgOutE


-- This function processes msgs from authenticated clients 
authenticatedMsgLoop :: MsgHandlerConfig -> IO ()
authenticatedMsgLoop msgHandlerConfig@MsgHandlerConfig {..}
 = do
  (catch
     (forever $ do
        msg <- WS.receiveData clientConn
        print msg
        let parsedMsg = parseMsgFromJSON msg
        print parsedMsg
        for_ parsedMsg $ handleSocketMsg msgHandlerConfig
        return ())
     (\e -> do
        let err = show (e :: WS.ConnectionException)
        print
          ("Warning: Exception occured in authenticatedMsgLoop for " ++
           show username ++ ": " ++ err)
        return ()))

-- takes a channel and if the player in the thread is the current player to act in the room 
-- then if no valid game action is received within 30 secs then we run the Timeout action
-- against the game
tableReceiveMsgLoop :: TableName -> TChan MsgOut -> MsgHandlerConfig -> IO ()
tableReceiveMsgLoop tableName channel msgHandlerConfig@MsgHandlerConfig {..} =
  forever $ do
    print "tableReceiveMsgLoop"
    dupChan <- atomically $ dupTChan channel
    chanMsg <- atomically $ readTChan dupChan
    sendMsg clientConn chanMsg
    if True
      then let timeoutMsg = GameMove tableName Timeout
               timeoutDuration = 5000000 -- 5 seconds for player to act
            in runTimedMsg timeoutDuration msgHandlerConfig tableName timeoutMsg
      else return ()

catchE :: TableName -> WS.ConnectionException -> IO MsgIn
catchE tableName e = do
  print e
  return $ GameMove tableName Timeout

-- Forks a new thread to run the timeout in then updates the game state 
-- with either the resulting timeout or player action
runTimedMsg :: Int -> MsgHandlerConfig -> TableName -> MsgIn -> IO ()
runTimedMsg duration msgHandlerConfig tableName timeoutMsg =
  withAsync
    (catch
       (awaitTimedMsg duration msgHandlerConfig tableName timeoutMsg)
       (catchE tableName)) $ \timedAction -> do
    playerActionE <- waitCatch timedAction
    let playerAction = fromRight timeoutMsg playerActionE
    handleSocketMsg msgHandlerConfig playerAction
    return ()

-- If the timeout occurs then we return the default msg 
awaitTimedMsg :: Int -> MsgHandlerConfig -> TableName -> MsgIn -> IO MsgIn
awaitTimedMsg duration msgHandlerConfig@MsgHandlerConfig {..} tableName defaultMsg = do
  maybeMsg <- timeout duration (WS.receiveData clientConn)
  return $ maybe defaultMsg parseWithDefaultMsg maybeMsg
  where
    timeoutDuration = 5000000
    parseWithDefaultMsg = (fromMaybe defaultMsg) . parseMsgFromJSON
```

Comment: It sounds as though the behavior you observe is consistent with the (closed) Github issue you link.  What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

Typically when a networking library throws an exception of some sort to indicate a closed connection, it is about an event outside of your control. The client has disconnected for some reason - perhaps they turned off their computer, for example.

You are being notified of that fact so you can react appropriately, for example by cleaning up the server-side resources allocated to that connection, or by alerting other clients who may care about this. You cannot turn the client's computer back on and force them to continue using your service. The connection *is* closed and there's nothing you can do to change that.

The behavior you describe matches perfectly the documentation you quote. The TCP connection is closed, and then you receive an exception to let you respond to that however you like. What do you imagine should happen differently?

Comment: Right but in this case the client is not closing the connection. The connection is being closed on the server side.

Comment: First: are you sure? That's not what the exception sounds like. Second: it doesn't really matter. You can try to prevent the connection being closed, but once you receive the exception it is too late. I am responding to "However even if I catch the exception as per the code below the client socket is still disconnected. This puzzles me." You need to look earlier in your program, to what event caused the client to close (if it was indeed server-side), and prevent that from occurring.

Comment: I think that the cause of the disconnection is related to the use of timeouts. Perhaps the timeout kills a thread which when blocked whilst receiving msgs from the client causes the connection to be terminated uncleanly?